# Whar are equivalent cross-browser solutions for window.showModalDialog?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, cross-browser, modal-dialog

Whar are equivalent cross-browser solutions for window.showModalDialog?
showModalDialog introduced in IE and FF 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively I think there are none. But there are lots of UI toolkits that provides such functionality, such as [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), the [dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and also the [Yahoo-UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

Comment: But is jQuery UI modal dialog accept a page url to be opened as modal dialog?

Comment: I don't think so, it uses a DIV element as a container for your stuff, but you could place an IFRAME element within it and load the URL you want.

Answer (score 1):

As of the asp.net tag: the ajax control toolkit has an ModalPopupExtender. Maybe this one is yours.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery UI provides dialogs and in this you can have a modal dialog also. Check out this

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

You can set the `modal` option to be `true` to get the modal dialog. See options section in this page.

```
$('.selector').dialog({ modal: true });
```